# iphone 6s freezing; passwords

Tags: iphone, password, performance

my iphone 6s plus has been freezing on me randomly and frequently. i have the most current ios. this was happening before the latest ios upgrade. i tried both soft and hard restarts. then i did a "reset all settings." it is still happening. i've researched how to fix it, i even called apple. apple and all comments about the problem have told me to rest using "erase all contents...." i would rather resolve the issue without doing that. does anyone have an idea how to solve the freezing problem? and, if i must reset all, how do i transfer/copy my current passwords so that i can import them back into my now factory set iphone? i back up my phone to icloud daily through auto backups and and i backup to my mac and often with itunes. i tried to find out if icloud keychain has my passwords stored there. but i can not locate keychain in my icloud. thanks. gregg

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is only one way to backup your passwords through iCloud: through iCloud Keychain. To check if your passwords are there, check all of the following:

1. On iOS: Settings > Passwords & Accounts > Website & App Passwords
2. On macOS: go to Keychain Access (`/Applications/Utilties/Keychain\ Access`), and on the sidebar to the left, there should be an entry called iCloud towards the top. Click on that, and sort by 'Kind', which should be the second column by default. Scroll down to the bottom, and you should see passwords with 'Web form password' in the 'Kind' column. Make sure that everything you want is there.